# Entity Framework with Condition Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to have a relationship that is based on a condition in Entity Framework? My model looks something like this...

```cs
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OwnerType OwnerType { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Organization OrganizationOwner { get; set; }
    public virtual User UserOwner { get; set; }
}

public enum OwnerType
{
    Organization = 1,
    User = 2
}

public class Organization
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //[other properties specific to Organization]

    public virtual List<Documents> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //[other properties specific to User]


    public virtual List<Documents> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

So, what I'd like to is set up a relationship so that the OrganizationOwner property of a Document instance automatically gets populated when the OwnerType == OwnerType.Organization, and the UserOwner property is populated when OwnerType == OwnerType.User.

Is this possible to set up this kind of relationship in EntityFramework - Code First? Something like this in the mapping...

```cs
EntityTypeConfiguration<Document>.HasOptional(d => d.OrganizationOwner)
    .WithMany(o => o.Documents)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.OwnerId)
    .Where(d => d.OwnerType == OwnerType.Organization);

EntityTypeConfiguration<Document>.HasOptional(d => d.UserOwner)
    .WithMany(u => u.Documents)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.OwnerId)
    .Where(d => d.OwnerType == OwnerType.User);
```

I would like to be able to leverage joins on the OrganizationOwner and UserOwner when setting up my Linq queries on the context so that I don't have to do a separate selects on those entities for each Document. Is this type of relationship supported or is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? We're having similar issues...